# .jinit() I get the typical "R session aborted" message

Tags: r, rjava

I just do as follows:

```
library(rJava) 
.jinit()
```

And I get the typical "R session aborted" message.
Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you have issues with Java and R configuration. Take a look here: [R, Java, rJava and macOS adventures](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3671)

If you work with R3.4, take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3718

If you have macOS, you will be able to proceed quite easily. If you work with Linux, it should be quite straightforward. For Windows, I am pretty sure you have to put jvm.dll on PATH in order to make it visible for R.